# .NET C# Synchronous Receive doesn't block

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

Recently I have tackled a strange behaviour of .Net synchronous receive method. I needed to write an application that has nodes which communicate with each other by sending/receiving data. Each server has a receipt loop which is synchronous, after receiving a serialized class it deserializes and processes it. After that it sends asynchronously this serialized class to some chosen nodes (using AsynchSendTo).

The MSDN clearly says that:

> "If you are using a connection-oriented Socket, the Receive method
>   will read as much data as is available, up to the size of the buffer.
>   If the remote host shuts down the Socket connection with the Shutdown
>   method, and all available data has been received, the Receive method
>   will complete immediately and return zero bytes."

In my case it's not true. There are some random cases when the Receive doesn't block and returns 0 bytes (non-deterministic situtation) right away after establishing connection. I'm 100% sure that the sender was sending at lest 1000 bytes. One more funny fact: when putting Sleep(500) before receive everything works just fine. Hereunder is the receiving code:

```
_listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
try
{
    _listener.Bind(_serverEndpoint);
    _listener.Listen(Int32.MaxValue);
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");
        Socket handler = _listener.Accept();

        int totalBytes = 0;
        int bytesRec;
        var bytes = new byte[DATAGRAM_BUFFER];
        do
        {
            //Thread.Sleep(500);
            bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes, totalBytes, handler.Available, SocketFlags.None);
            totalBytes += bytesRec;
        } while (bytesRec > 0);

        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        handler.Close();
    }
}
catch (SocketException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Also the sending part:

```
public void AsynchSendTo(Datagram datagram, IPEndPoint recipient)
{

    byte[] byteDatagram = SerializeDatagram(datagram);
    try
    {
        var socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        socket.BeginConnect(recipient, ConnectCallback, new StateObject(byteDatagram, byteDatagram.Length, socket));
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}

public void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        var stateObject = (StateObject)result.AsyncState;
        var socket = stateObject.Socket;
        socket.EndConnect(result);
        socket.BeginSend(stateObject.Data, 0, stateObject.Data.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("catched!" + ex.ToString());
    }
}

public void SendCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        var client = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
        client.EndSend(result);
        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        client.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}

class StateObject
{
    public Byte[] Data { get; set; }
    public int Size;
    public Socket Socket;
}
```

My question: am I using the synchronous receive in a wrong way? Why it doesn't block event though there is data to receive?

Comment: Since your question isn't specifically about the problem you're having that's resolved with a sleep before the read. Since half a second each loop can really take a toll with latency if a lot is being read at once, have you tried sleeping after the read with a smaller sleep time like 100msecs? This has worked for me with reading from serial ports but that was also when a data received event occurred as well.

Comment: This just isn't the way Socket works.  Start diagnosing this by removing all the try/catch blocks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're shooting yourself in the foot.

```
bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes, totalBytes, handler.Available, SocketFlags.None);
```

At the very beginning of the connection, `Available` will be 0, forcing it to return immediately with 0. Instead, you should specify the number of bytes which are free in your buffer (e.g. `bytes.Length-totalBytes`), then it will also block.

Answer (score 6):

You may have a concurrency problem here. After you accept a connection, you jump straight into receive. The sender process may not have enough time to reach the call to send and so your `handler.Available` is 0 and the receive returns.

This is also why the "bug" does not occur when you add the sleep of 500 ms.

Comment: I think I also added the reason why 500 ms fixes it. I didn't copy your answer...

Comment: Sorry, my intention was *not* to make your answer look as if it was copied from mine. Nevertheless, they essentially say the same - mine implicitly addresses the different behavior with the delay with the "At the very beginning..." sentence. ;)